# How To Delete An Object inside a Field in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Self taught coder here. I'm trying to make a function that would delete a specific object inside a field within firebase. It's for something similar to a to-do app. Inside my firebase structure, here is what I'm trying to delete (either object 0 or 1 as pointed out with red arrows:

[image]

My function looks like this but I don't think I can use bracket notation, and I haven't had any luck with dot notation either.

```
  const deleteLabel = async (id) => {
    await updateDoc(labelCollectionRef, currentUser.uid, {
      labels: arrayRemove(1),
    });
    console.log("label deleted!");
  };
```

I've had a few errors, the main one right now being this:

Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'ba', but it was: a custom va object

Comment: If you see the answer below, `updateDoc()` only takes 2 params but you are passing 3 and the 1st one is not a DocumentReference created by using `doc()` function and hence the new error. And you must pass the "entire" object that must be removed not just 1.

Comment: Is this what you mean when you say "entire" object? I've changed my code above in question.

Comment: You don't need the `0: {`. Just the value so it should be `arrayRemove({ cards: [....], id: "nba" })`. Also include the id field as that is part of the object.

Comment: Thanks Dharmaraj. I feel I'm getting quite close to solving this. I've updated the question above with your tips. Between you and Frank, I owe you both a beer!

Comment: The `[...]` was meant to be replaced by the actual data in that array that you had added in the previous post i.e. those 2 objects containing name and tag. Make sure their order is same in the array.

Comment: Darn. I thought so. I tried that first and then thought maybe you meant it as a spread operator or something. This code above produces the same error. Appreciate the help.

Comment: `await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", currentUser.uid), {...})`. Again replace with the object you've created so far in update data

Answer (score 2):

The `deleteField` operator can only be applied to a complete field, like for example the entire `labels` array. It cannot be used to remove a single item from that array.

To remove an item from the field, you can use the [`arrayRemove` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_11), passing in the entire content of the item in the array as the value:

```
updateDoc(doc(db, "users", currentUser.uid), {
  labels: arrayRemove({id: "nhl"}),
});
```

Comment: Thanks Frank! I tried this but I'm getting an error saying "firebase is not defined." I'm importing it like so: 
import {
  collection,
  doc,
  setDoc,
  getDoc,
  arrayUnion,
  updateDoc,
  deleteField,
  FieldValue,
} from "firebase/firestore"

Any idea why it's not defined all of a sudden?

Comment: Oh right... You're using the v9 syntax, so see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_11

Comment: Hmm I worry maybe I'm not explaining my issue correctly. I've updated the question with your comments in mind. Thank you very much for the advice thus far!

Comment: Hey @jakeycodez. Please don't make such broad changes to the existing question, as it makes my answer meaningless for future visitors. I've rolled back the changes to prevent that. --- If you want to clarify where you are stuck now, edit your question to show the new code as an update at the bottom. Keep in mind though, that your original code uses `deleteField`, which doesn't work for the reason I explained. If you have problems getting `arrayRemove` to work, that might well be a new problem.

Comment: No problem at all. I'm still learning the best methods to explain my problems and will definitely consider this in the future. In the moment I was so consumed with figuring out a solution that I didn't realize how confusing this thread process might look to others looking for help as well. My apologies. Thanks again!

Comment:  I'd still love to see why `arrayRemove` isn't working for you, so let me know when you've *added* that to your question here, or have posted a separate question about that. --- Keep in mind that the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73955442/revisions) of your question is available, so you still can find what you posted in there.

Comment: I think it wasn't working because I didn't have the entire object data formatted correctly. I have it hardcoded now and it works! So now I just need to reformat to have it delete dynamically ;)

Comment: Ah yeah, that is indeed important. At the lowest level the database performs a comparison of the protobufs to determine if there's a matching item, so it's quite unforgiving on differences.